# Using $(this) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, this

I'm still a jquery/javascript newbie, so forgive me if this is an obvious one.

I'm making an artist bio page for a conference (it's up here in live view http://www.thinkinc.org.au/artists.html ). When you click an artist's image, a colorbox opens up with artist bio and videos. When clicking the thumbnails, I want to send a .remove() command to the initial video ("initvid") of the speaker the user is viewing.

The offending javascript code is here:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.thumbnails img').click(function () {
            $('#initvid')+$(this).attr('id').remove(); /* I want this to get #initvid + the id of the thumbnail image that was clicked (to make #initvidtyson or #initvidhitchens) then .remove() it */

            $('#vidContainer').html('<iframe id="playingMovie" width="480" height="390" src="' + $(this).attr('toobId') +'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

            $('#vidContainer iframe').fadeToggle(400);
        });
    });
```

If you look at the code for my thumbnails, each has an id for the artist whose bio they belong to. (e.g.  ; ). I want to create a jquery function that removes #initvidhitchens or #initvidtyson (depending on which bio thumbs are being clicked).

Probably missing something quite obvious, but why isn't my current code working?

Comment: If it's the same container for all the videos, why do you need to remove and add when you can just overwrite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
$('#initvid' + $(this).attr('id')).remove();
```

or this:

```
$('#initvid'+this.id).remove();
```

Your code wasn't working because:

```
 $('#initvid') + //Here you're getting element with id 'initvid', which doesn't exist
 $(this).attr('id').remove();  //The result of getting id attribute wasn't a jQuery object, so it doesn't have 'remove' method
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#initvid' + $(this).attr('id')).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Close. The *string* passed to `$` is what needs to have the extra identifier concatenated.

```
$('#initvid' + $(this).attr('id')).remove();
```

Think of it as:

```
$('#initvid' + extra) // the *result* of the string concat is used as the selector
```

However, depending upon exact problem, there may be cleaner methods to accomplish this task.

Happy coding.

Comment: Ah, understood. Very glad to see I was _almost_ right! Cheers mate.